# put a scroll bar in php

Tags: php, database, scroll

this is my code to display a large number of queries in php
i wated to know how to include a horizontal scroll bar in this code i tried including with div tag but it shows blank space at that place

```
 <?php 
          global $row2;
          $query2= "select title,created_at, featured_image, description from news_portal.posts where featured= '1' ; "; 
          $query_result2=mysqli_query($conn2 ,$query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
          while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array($query_result2)) { ?>

          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
            <div class="h2-news-block">
              <div class="nthumb">
                <div class="ndate"> Nov <strong><?php echo $row2['created_at'];?></strong> </div>
                <img src="http://media.mintlime.in/uploads/images/<?php echo $row2['featured_image'];?>" alt=""></div>
              <div class="ntxt">
                <ul class="news-meta">
                  <li><a href="#">Hospital</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Schools</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Banks</a></li>
                </ul>
                <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $row2['title'];?></a></h4>
                <p><?php echo $row2['description'];?></p>
              </div>
              <div class="news-footer">
                <ul>
                  <li class="pull-left"> <a href="#" class="nd">News Detail <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a> </li>
                  <li class="pull-right">
                    <div class="dropup"> <a href="#" class="nshare" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                        <li> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a> <a href="<?php echo $row2['']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a> </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `style="overflow-x: scroll;"` to the div?

Comment: yes adding that makes the whole content place blank

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle of generated HTML? Or simply provide generated HTML file with relevant stylesheet used.

Comment: i solved it and i just wanted to ask do u know how to fetch the latest inserted queries i